# List comprehension con if, 2 bucles anidados en ortools

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que recurre a ortools para resolver un problema. Estoy intentando quitar en lo posible los bucles for y sustituirlos por list comprehension, hasta ahora me ha ido bien pero tengo este que no logro cambiar:

```
for f in L_Filas:
    for c in L_Columnas:
        if tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] :
            s.Add(x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] - 1] == 1)
```

Ésa estructura funciona bien en el programa.
He intentado quitar el más interno (el bucle de la variable c) para ir probando:

```py
for f in L_filas:
    [s.Add((x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] - 1] for c in L_Columnas if tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1])==1)]
```

Pero no me funciona. No da errores de sintaxis ni nada, sino que simplemente el programa termina y me devuelve un resultado erróneo.

¿Dónde me estoy equivocando?

Comment: El `s.Add()` no tendría que ir fuera de los `[]`, rodeando la lista entera devuelta por la list comprehension??

Comment: No se si te entiendo bien. Otra de las partes del programa era esta:
`    for f in L_Filas:
        for v in L_Valores:
            s.Add(sum(x[f][c][v] for c in range(9)) == 1)`
y ha funcionado bien cambiando por esto:
`
    [[[s.Add(sum(x[f][c][v] for c in range(9))==1)] for v in L_Valores] for f in L_Filas]
`
No veo clara tu sugerencia.

Comment: Ignora mi sugerencia pues. Al menos la primera, porque esta te recomiendo seguirla: Añade datos de prueba en la pregunta para que podamos ejecutar el código y modificarlo. Es imposible de cabeza y sin estar viendo qué pinta tienen los datos saber qué está pasando. Añade un ejemplo de entrada y la salida correspondiente

Comment: Te agradezco mucho el consejo, de hecho lo he pensado bastante pero siempre me quedo con la duda de cuánto es suficiente y cuánto es excesivo. El programa es un poco largo, y ésto es sólo una pequeña parte. Pero para ver lo que hace, debería ponerlo entero, y tampoco quiero que me llamen la atención por poner mucho código para resolver una pequeña duda. Iré aprendiendo. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No te digo que pongas *todo* tu programa. Te digo que pongas los datos de entrada a ese método, es decir, lo que hay contenido en tu L_Filas (y tablaOrigD) justo antes de entrar al bucle que no te sale, así como los datos de salida DE ESE MÉTODO. De nuevo, **NO** de *todo* el programa. Pero sin datos para debugar el método que te da error... cómo pretendes que sepamos exactamente si funciona o no list comprehension si no podemos probarla??? Si no nos proporcionas un caso de prueba válido para tu código, no podemos saber si lo que hacemos es correcto, ergo no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Ah ok. Bueno, pues se me escapa de mi nivel, porque las variables del solver (las x[i][j][k] son internas y no sé cómo verlas. Uso Spyder normalmente. Sólo puedo decir si el programa resuelve el problema correctamente o no. Lo dejaré como está.

Comment: que es `s`? qué hace su método `.Add()`? porque entiendo que la verdadera razón de una list comprehension sería rellenar `s`, pero _sin usar Add_, y antes de responder cómo se haría eso, es necesario saber que tipo de contenedor es `s`.

Comment: @abulafia, s es un objeto "solver" de las librerías ortools. Avisaba en el título de ello pues puede despistar bastante. Add es un método que añade variables de decisión y/o restricciones al objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, la solución es esta:

```
[s.Add(x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1] - 1] == 1) for f in L_Filas for c in L_Columnas if tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1]]
```

No es mía, me ha ayudado @Simon en la página en inglés.

Comment: Manuel, te recomiendo que en lugar de simplemente copiar y pegar, des una explicación sobre cómo es que ese código responde la pregunta.

Comment: Cierto. Lo que pasa es que primero tuve que estudiar yo porqué así sí funcionaba, je je. Lo que ocurre es que yo intentaba hacer una LC "anidada", y en realidad es una sola lista que tiene los dos bucles y el condicional, todo en la misa.

Answer (score 0):

No deben usarse comprensiones de listas por sus efectos secundarios. La misión de una comprensión de listas es crear una lista.

En tu caso en cambio la lista que estás creando no tiene sentido porque:

1. No la asignas a ninguna variable
2. No se sabe qué contiene, pues contiene el resultado de cada uno de los `s.Add()` que haces. Esa función no está definida y no sabemos qué retorna.

En el fondo, tu lista es similar a esta otra que ya he visto en más de una ocasión:

```
[print(n**2) for n in range(1, 21)]
```

que quiere imprimir la lista de los primeros 20 cuadrados perfectos. En realidad sí que está imprimiendo eso, pero utilizar una lista de comprehensión para ello es **un antipatrón**. La función `print()` retorna `None` y por tanto estamos creando una lista que contiene 20 Nones. A pesar de ello "funciona" debido al efecto secundario del print, que muestra por pantalla su argumento aunque retorne None.

Aunque la comprensión de listas suele ser una solución más Pythónica en muchos casos, ello no significa que haya que reemplazar todos los bucles `for` que aparezcan en un programa por una comprensión de listas. Hay casos (como este) en el que no se gana nada, y si acaso se empeora la legibilidad. El ejemplo que acabo de poner estaría mucho mejor así:

```
for n in range(1, 21):
   print(n**2)
```

Perfectamente legible y evita el desperdicio de memoria y tiempo necesarios para crear una lista temporal con 20 None que de todas formas no se va a almacenar en ningún lugar.

Lo mismo te está ocurriendo a ti con tu comprensión de listas. La implementación inicial en un bucle `for` *era mejor*, pues la lista que estás construyendo con los resultados de `s.Add()` requiere tiempo y memoria, y en realidad *no quieres esa lista*, sólo quieres el "efecto secundario" (que se añadan elementos a `s`).

Si acaso, entiendo que quieras reducir la complejidad del código eliminando el bucle anidado (no lo has conseguido porque ese bucle anidado sigue existiendo dentro de la comprensión de listas, más difícil aún de entender). Puedes evitar anidaciones de bucles si haces uso de la función `itertools.product`. En este caso sería así:

```py
from itertools import product

for f, c in product(L_Filas, L_Columnas):
  if tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1]:
    s.Add(x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] - 1] == 1)
```

Comment: Bueno en este caso y dado de lo que estamos hablando, sí tiene sentido usar ésto para dejar más claro qué es lo que se añade al objeto solver.